# How do I get my program to run on different machines without needing an installer?

Tags: mysql, vb.net, installation, jit, connector

I've created a program which is using a MySql.* reference for MySql commands. The program works great on my own PC, where I have the MySQL Connector/NET installed. Although when trying to use the program on another PC, it gives me a JIT error saying MySql.Data reference is missing.

Note: I don't actually publish the program duo to it's simplicity and because I prefer having a portable application, so I just grab the exe out of my `Visual Studio\Projects\appDayZAdmin\appDayZAdmin\bin\Debug` folder.

Is there any way for me to get this program to work on other PC's who don't necessarily have the connector installed? Or will I have no other option but to actually publish the project thus making an installer for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you've written code to reference MySql.Data, you're going to either have to make it a precondition for using your program or offer a way to install it.

You might be able to assume availability of some generic database interface like OBDC or JDBC, but that won't be true on some percentage of systems. Even then, you may have versioning issues.

Comment: How would one go at it to make it a precondition? Or do you mean just basically tell people they need to install before using it? If there's no workaround without requiring people to install the connector, I'll probably just publish it & have them install my program instead of just running an .exe

Comment: Without an installer for your program to check for it, all you can do is tell them they need the connector. Maybe you could supply a link to the connector's installer in your app's startup routine if it doesn't find it.

Comment: Hmm, in that case I'll probably just do it with an .iso & have it installed from a disc (image). Thanks anyway :)